# Extract data from splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a Post query where I want to extract request payload or parameters and print a table. In the query, I am trying to extract the user_search **name** field

I have written a Splunk query but it is not working for me

```
"Parameters: {\"user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>*"  | rex  field=_raw "/\"user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>/(?<result>.*)"  | table result
```

**Splunk Data**

```
I, [2021-09-23T00:46:31.172197 #44154]  INFO -- : [651235bf-7ad5-4a2e-a3b8-7737a3af9fc3]   Parameters: {"user_search"=>{"name"=>"aniket", "has_primary_phone"=>"false", "query_params"=>{"searchString"=>"", "start"=>"0", "filters"=>[""]}}}
host = qa-1132-lx02source = /src/project.logsourcetype = data:log

I, [2021-09-23T00:48:31.162197 #44154]  INFO -- : [651235bf-7ad5-4a2e-a3b8-7737a3af9fc3]   Parameters: {"user_search"=>{"name"=>"shivam", "has_primary_phone"=>"false", "query_params"=>{"searchString"=>"", "start"=>"0", "filters"=>[""]}}}
host = qa-1132-lx02source = /src/project.logsourcetype = data:log

I, [2021-09-23T00:52:27.171197 #44154]  INFO -- : [651235bf-7ad5-4a2e-a3b8-7737a3af9fc3]   Parameters: {"user_search"=>{"name"=>"tiwari", "has_primary_phone"=>"false", "query_params"=>{"searchString"=>"", "start"=>"0", "filters"=>[""]}}}
host = qa-1132-lx02source = /src/project.logsourcetype = data:log
```

I have 2 questions

1. How to write a splunk query to extract request payload in post query
2. In my above query I am not not sure what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate if someone has any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the least, your regular expression has an error

You have:

```
"/\"user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>/(?<result>.*)"
```

There is an extra "`/`" after the "`=>`"

[This](https://regex101.com/r/dSNyhI/1) seems to pull what you're looking for:

```
user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>(?<result>.*)
```

#### Edit per comment "*I only want to fetch the values such as aniket & shivam from the name key*"

There're a couple ways to do what you're asking, and which is going to be more performant will depend on your environment and data

##### Option 1

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ("aniket" OR "shivam")
| rex field=_raw "user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>(?<result>.*)"
| stats count by result
```

##### Option 2

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp
| rex field=_raw "user_search\"=>{\"name\"=>(?<result>.*)"
| search result="aniket" OR result="shivam"
| stats count by result
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I only want to fetch the values such as  aniket & shivam from the name key

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari - see update

Comment: The values will be dynamic. Why you have fixed it to "aniket" or "shivam". I can have n number of values

Comment: When I say aniket or shivam that was an example. I need a way to fetch dynamic values for the name key

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari - you're the one who said you wanted to find particular values: "*But I only want to fetch the values such as aniket & shivam from the name key*" :). I even explained this in the comment accompanying my edit t my answer. Changing that requirement to "*I need a way to fetch dynamic values for the name key*" is fine, but it *is* a different requirement.

Comment: okay Let me add a new question.